# SharePoint Alternate Access Mappings: Event Receiver only fires when accessing the site using localhost but not with IP or machine

Tags: sharepoint, alternate-access-mappings

**Context**

We have a SharePoint site set up on a Windows Server 2008 VM box.

We also developed a SP event receiver in C# and registered it with the appropriate SP site and subscribed to the following events:

ItemDeleted;

ItemFileMoved;

ItemUpdated;

**The following is list of SP info:**

- local machine name: testsp;
- local ip: 10.152.0.248;
- port: 80;

**Alternate Access Mappings**

**internal  Zone      public**

- http://localhost   default   http://testsp
- http://testsp      default   http://testsp
- http://10.152.0.248 default  http://10.152.0.248

**Issue/Symptom**

When using SP site is accessed from IE using localhost as a URL, and when a document is deleted and added, the subscribed events fire.  But if I use testsp or the ip address the events don't fire.

My suspicion lies with AAM but cannot figure out where.

**Please help**

If any SP guru could point out the issue, I'd be most grateful.

TIA,

Cullen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the user who logged in to upload to SharePoint has no permission to write to Windows Event Log.